# ImageMagick MacPorts install fails on Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, imagemagick, macports

I recently upgraded to Snow Leopard. I installed the new XCode Tools and the X11 optional install. I upgraded to the new Snow Leopard binary of MacPorts, did a port selfupdate, reinstalled all ports and ImageMagick wasn't working. I uninstalled the ImageMagick port, reinstalled it, and got the following error trace:

```
    $ sudo port install imagemagick
--->  Computing dependencies for ImageMagick
--->  Fetching ImageMagick
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for ImageMagick
--->  Extracting ImageMagick
--->  Configuring ImageMagick
--->  Building ImageMagick
Error: Target org.macports.build returned: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_graphics_ImageMagick/work/ImageMagick-6.5.6-1" && /usr/bin/make -j2 all " returned error 2
Command output:       _XSetTextColor in magick_libMagickCore_la-widget.o
      _XSetTextColor in magick_libMagickCore_la-widget.o
      _XSetTextColor in magick_libMagickCore_la-widget.o
      _XSetMatteColor in magick_libMagickCore_la-widget.o
      _XSetBevelColor in magick_libMagickCore_la-widget.o
      _XSetBevelColor in magick_libMagickCore_la-widget.o
      _XDrawMatte in magick_libMagickCore_la-widget.o
      _XDrawBeveledButton in magick_libMagickCore_la-widget.o
      _XDrawImage in magick_libMagickCore_la-xwindow.o
  "_XQueryColor", referenced from:
      _XGetWindowColor in magick_libMagickCore_la-xwindow.o
  "_XDefaultColormap", referenced from:
      _XAnimateImages in magick_libMagickCore_la-animate.o
      _XAnimateImages in magick_libMagickCore_la-animate.o
      _XAnimateImages in magick_libMagickCore_la-animate.o
      _RenderType in magick_libMagickCore_la-annotate.o
      _XDisplayImage in magick_libMagickCore_la-display.o
      _XDisplayImage in magick_libMagickCore_la-display.o
      _XDisplayImage in magick_libMagickCore_la-display.o
      _XQueryColorDatabase in magick_libMagickCore_la-xwindow.o
      _XSelectWindow in magick_libMagickCore_la-xwindow.o
      _XFreeStandardColormap in magick_libMagickCore_la-xwindow.o
      _XMakeStandardColormap in magick_libMagickCore_la-xwindow.o
      _XMakeStandardColormap in magick_libMagickCore_la-xwindow.o
      _XMakeStandardColormap in magick_libMagickCore_la-xwindow.o
      _XMakeStandardColormap in magick_libMagickCore_la-xwindow.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [magick/libMagickCore.la] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
```

Any ideas? I already have all the ImageMagick dependency ports installed. Should I try reinstalling them all?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question just in case someone else has this problem as well. I thought the problem might be in a dependency, so I could either reinstall every ImageMagick dependency (there are like 20), in the proper order, or I could blow away MacPorts and reinstall them all. I chose the latter. ImageMagick built with no problems after.

Comment: Likely you had an incomplete build directory from Leopard days that got carried through the migration.  MacPorts used that partially built port and things went downhill from there.